# updating a cell with a concatenated reference from another sheet

Tags: excel

I'm having trouble starting this VBA code.

I have two spreadsheets Sheet 1 and Sheet 2 that have data for clients. 
The one column in sheet 2 has a value set to a number + Sales Office location(ie 750-UNKNOWN, 841-UNKNOWN, 160-NC - GREENVILLE). I want to search that  column for the "Unknown" value and use the number from that value ie 750 to match it from another worksheet (Sheet 1) by looking up the appropriate value and updating the cell in sheet 2 to that number and the name in the next cell by concatenating it in the cell.

Sheet 2

- ### Reference

-771-UNKNOWN (cell H2)

- 720-UNKNOWN (Cell h3)

  - Sheet 1
    A           B
    New FSO New FSO Name
    105 (A2)        Kentucky (B2)
    60  (A3)       Taft-Hartley (B3)

I don't know where to begin with doing this.

Additionally, I need to set a rule that if the value isn't found during the search ie if 750 isn't in the list, then return "No Sales Office located"

Thank you!

Comment: Kimberly, welcome to SO. You should do some research on VBA, learn how it works and how to use. Then, if you have an specific question, you should post it here.

Answer (score 0):

If(mid(h2, len(h2)-7),7) = "unknown", left(h2, len(h2)-7),"no sales office") the 7 would change if unknown is Utah (then it would be 4).

Comment: Thank you! 
Is there a way to automate this by adding code to a button to go through each line automatically and make the updates?

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't add the value from the vlookup to the cell=IF(MID(K3,(LEN(K3)-5),7)="unknown",VLOOKUP(LEFT(K3,3),FinalFSOTbl!A:B,1,FALSE),"no sales office")